# How to add shadow to SwiftUI arc?

Tags: ios, swift, gradient, swiftui

I have the following arc:

```
struct Arc : Shape
{
    @Binding var endAngle: Double
    var center: CGPoint
    var radius: CGFloat
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path
    {
        var path = Path()

        path.addArc(center: center, radius: radius, startAngle: .degrees(270), endAngle: .degrees(endAngle), clockwise: false)

        return path.strokedPath(.init(lineWidth: 50, lineCap: .round))
    }
}
```

How can I add shadow, similar to the activity arcs on Apple Watch, such that at full circle the endAngle is still discernible?

EDIT:
There's the additional issue at 360+ degrees (so full circle), that both arc ends get combined and are shown as a radial line (I see this because I've a applied an `AngularGradient`). Of course `Arc` won't do advanced things like continuing above the `startAngle` position, like the Apple Watch arcs do. But this was what I was looking for. Does anyone know how to do that in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

what about this? ok...bit "tricky"

```
import SwiftUI

    struct Arc: Shape {
    
    @Binding var startAngle: Double
    @Binding var endAngle: Double
    
    var center: CGPoint
    var radius: CGFloat
    var color: Color
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        
        let cgPath = CGMutablePath()
        cgPath.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY), radius: radius, startAngle: CGFloat(startAngle), endAngle: CGFloat(endAngle), clockwise: true)
        
      //  path.addArc(center: center, radius: radius, startAngle: .degrees(270), endAngle: .degrees(endAngle), clockwise: false)
    
        path = Path(cgPath)
        
        return path.strokedPath(.init(lineWidth: 50, lineCap: .round))
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack() {
       //     Arc(endAngle: .constant(269), center: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200), radius: 150, color: .red).foregroundColor(.red).opacity(0.2)
            Arc(startAngle: .constant(80 + 271), endAngle: .constant(80 + 271 + 340), center: CGPoint(x: 205, y: 205), radius: 150, color: .red).foregroundColor(.red)//.shadow(color: .black, radius: 5, x: -30, y: -170)
            Arc(startAngle: .constant(90), endAngle: .constant(80 + 270), center: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200), radius: 150, color: .red).foregroundColor(.red).shadow(color: .black, radius: 5, x: -114, y: -230)
        }
         .background(Color.black)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, wasn't expecting it to be that simple to add this nice shadow. SwiftUI is pretty powerful. In the mean time, I've edited my question, explaining that I want the arc to continue above the `startAngle` at full circle and beyond, which is what the Apple Watch arcs do. Do you have ideas?

Comment: it is possible....check this out...https://github.com/maxkonovalov/MKRingProgressView

Comment: That doesn't seem to be SwiftUI unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

do you mean something like this?

```
struct Arc : Shape
{
    @Binding var endAngle: Double

    var center: CGPoint
    var radius: CGFloat
    var color: Color

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path
    {
        var path = Path()

        path.addArc(center: center, radius: radius, startAngle: .degrees(270), endAngle: .degrees(endAngle), clockwise: false)

        return path.strokedPath(.init(lineWidth: 50, lineCap: .round))
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack() {
            Arc(endAngle: .constant(269), center: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200), radius: 150, color: .red).foregroundColor(.red).opacity(0.2)
            Arc(endAngle: .constant(90), center: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200), radius: 150, color: .red).foregroundColor(.red)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No. This does not create a shadow at all, it results in just a colored circle where `endAngle` is not discernable at 360+ degrees, and hence does not look like the Apple Watch activity arcs at all. http://osxdaily.com/2016/01/21/share-activity-progress-apple-watch-iphone/

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can fix and handle all of these features by writing an extension in your project file

```
    import UIKit
extension UIView {
func roundCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.path = path.cgPath
    self.layer.mask = mask
}

// MARK: Shadow extension UIView {

func dropShadow(scale: Bool = true) {
    layer.masksToBounds = false
    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1.5, height: 3)
    layer.shadowRadius = 3

    layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds).cgPath
    layer.shouldRasterize = true
    layer.rasterizationScale = scale ? UIScreen.main.scale : 1
}

func dropShadow(color: UIColor, opacity: Float = 0.5, offSet: CGSize, radius: CGFloat = 1, scale: Bool = true) {
    layer.masksToBounds = false
    layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
    layer.shadowOpacity = opacity
    layer.shadowOffset = offSet
    layer.shadowRadius = radius

    layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).cgPath
    layer.shouldRasterize = true
    layer.rasterizationScale = scale ? UIScreen.main.scale : 1
}

func setAnchorPoint(_ point: CGPoint) {
    var newPoint = CGPoint(x: bounds.size.width * point.x, y: bounds.size.height * point.y)
    var oldPoint = CGPoint(x: bounds.size.width * layer.anchorPoint.x, y: bounds.size.height * layer.anchorPoint.y)

    newPoint = newPoint.applying(transform)
    oldPoint = oldPoint.applying(transform)

    var position = layer.position

    position.x -= oldPoint.x
    position.x += newPoint.x

    position.y -= oldPoint.y
    position.y += newPoint.y

    layer.position = position
    layer.anchorPoint = point
}

class func fromNib<T: UIView>() -> T {
    guard let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(String(describing: T.self), owner: nil, options: nil)?.first as? T else { fatalError() }
    return view
}
```

now in storyboard you can handle shadows
or you don't want to, and it's too much, you can use the only part you need.

Comment: i think he meant SwiftUI ....of course you can use Representable...i know ;)

Comment: As @Chris indicated I want this in pure SwiftUI.